# class instance returned in a static method doesn't match type

Tags: flowtype

I'm returning an instance of class in a static method but flow is complaining about incompatible generic type. Is this a problem with flow or am I doing something wrong?

Code:

```
class Foo<T> {
    var1: T
    constructor(var1: T) {
        this.var1 = var1
    }
    static staticMethod(var1: T) {
        return new Foo(var1)
    }
}

let x:Foo<number> = new Foo(1) // works
let y:Foo<number> = Foo.staticMethod(1) // doesn't work
```

Error:

```
let y:Foo<number> = Foo.staticMethod(1)
                    ^ Cannot assign `Foo.staticMethod(...)` to `y` because `T` [1] is incompatible with number [2] in type argument `T` [3].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like flow can't infer the type here, but it works fine if you annotate the return type.

Change

```
static staticMethod(var1: T) {
```

to

```
static staticMethod(var1: T): Foo<T> {
```